# Python command-line breakdown (for "scrapy")

Tags: python, windows-7, scrapy

I was trying to install SCRAPY and play with it.

The tutorial says to run this:

```
   scrapy startproject tutorial
```

Can you please break this down to help me understand it.  I have various releases of Python on my Windows 7 machine for various conflicting projects, so when I installed Scrapy with their .exe, it installed it in c:\Python26_32bit directory, which is okay.  But I don't have any one version of Python in my path.

So I tried:

```
\python26_32bit\python.exe scrapy startproject tutorial
```

and I get the error:

```
\python26_32bit\python.exe: can't open file 'scrapy': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

I do see scrapy installed here: c:\Python26_32bit\Lib\site-packages\scrapy

I cannot find any file called scrapy.py, so what exactly is "scrapy" in Python terminology, a lib, a site-package, a program, ?? and how do I change the sample above to run?

I'm a little more used to Python in Google App Engine environment, so running on my local machine is often more challenging and foreign to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scrapy is a batch file which execute a python file called "scrapy", so you need to add the file "scrapy"'s path to your PATH environment.

if that is still not work, make "scrapy.py" file with content

```
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
execute()
```

and run `\python26_32bit\python.exe scrapy.py startproject tutorial`

Comment: How standard is this?  c:\Python26_32bit\Scripts\scrapy.bat and c:\Python26_32bit\Scripts\scrapy with NO .py extension, but yet I think it is .py code.  I never knew to look in the "Scripts" subdir of the Python install directory.

Comment: Also had to install Twisted and ZopeInterface to get Scrapy to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
C:\Python26_32bit\Scripts\Scrapy startproject tutorial
```

or 
add `C:\Python26_32bit\Scripts` to your path

Answer (score 0):

I ran accross this error with the following setup: Python installed on Windows. Cygwin (babun) installed. Used `pip install Scrapy` from the Windows installation (Scrapy now in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\scrapy). Wanted to use Scrapy from within babun. Got the same error as you. What you can do:

In your .bashrc/.zshrc/etc, add the following:

`alias scrapy='python.exe -mscrapy.cmdline'`

I can now run scrapy inside babun without any problems.

Note: I also had to run `pip install service_identity` manually.