# Scrapy suspend console on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I started using [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) library on my Windows 10 machine.

When running scrapy by

```
>scrapy startproject myproject
```

it **suspends / freeze** my console.

I have `%PYTHONHOME%\Scripts\` in my `PATH` so it runs executable from (`%PYTHONHOME%\Scripts\scrapy.exe`), which is the default path of installed scrapy.

#### The question is

How I can fix this - to run scrapy from it's executable and why it could happened?

#### My environment:

- Windows 10
- Python 2.7.11

(!) [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132423/python-command-line-breakdown-for-scrapy) is not exactly the same

---

### Workaround

Actually I've found workaround.

Running scrapy from it's command line tool works from python works.

```
python -m scrapy.cmdline startproject myproject
```

Comment: Can confirm same issue on Windows 10 and can confirm fix worked. Thanks!

Comment: Also, it won't let me do a 1 character edit but for future users there should be a space between the `-m` and the `scrapy.cmdline` so it should read `python -m scrapy.cmdline startproject myproject`.

Comment: @fdsa thanks for pointing this out, I've edited the question :) I'm glad that my workaround helped