# C:\Python37\python.exe: can't open file 'scrapy': [Errno 2] No such file or dire ctory

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

My paths environment in windows 7:

```
C:\Python37\Scripts\;
C:\Python37\;
C:\Python37\Scripts\scrapy.exe;
C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\scrapy
```

Few days ago, without modified stuffs since, I used to run my spider like this:

```
py scrapy crawl spider -a arg1=truc -a arg2=machin
```

*I run it in the project spider as `C:\Users\Truc\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\...\spiders`*
it worked well, no problem, but today by a magic I obtain this message:

```
C:\Python37\python.exe: can't open file 'scrapy': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How is it possible when I did not change anything?

### some update

I did try the solution of @YOU in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132423/python-command-line-breakdown-for-scrapy), so create a `.py` file in `C:\Users\Truc\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\...\spiders` edited it as said, and obtain this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "C:\Users\Truc\FolderA\FolderB\FolderC\...\spiders\scrapy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy.cmdline'; 'scrapy' is not a package
```

I did check if there is `cmdline` and there is, but `'scrapy' is not a package` is this weird.

Comment: Are you sure that `C:\Python37\Scripts\scrapy.exe` is a folder?

Comment: @Matthias yes I am sure and checked it again because you asked me and it is in this folder.

Comment: @AvyWam What @Matthias meant is that the `PATH` environment variable is for folders. That is the path of an executable, you should remove it from the `PATH`, the only entry you need to be able to run that executable is `C:\Python37\Scripts\ `, which you alrelady have in the `PATH`.

Comment: @Gallaecio it was the case before and it did not work at all too. I added those because I saw it in some topics but it changed nothing.

Comment: @AvyWam Try the approach in my updated response.

Comment: @Matthias I did some update, have a look if you want to.

Comment: @Gallaecio I did some update, have a look if you want to

Answer (score 0):

Test it in the python REPL if you can import scrapy.

Comment: I did, it works well actually with `py` Enter `import scrapy`, no issue.

Comment: so if you want scapy package to be imported, you would need to add `__init__.py` inside of that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Change `py scrapy` to simply `scrapy` in your call.

Comment: @AvyWam Try this other approach.

Comment: Actually if I ask for py it is because I want to run my spider with another version of python, the 3.7.2, because there is only one module which only work with python 3.X, calling scrapy alone use the default python where the module I was talking about is not compatible. Besides even with reinstallation it still does not work, that is a huge mystery.

Comment: When you install Scrapy, the .exe file is configured to use the Python version that you used to install Scrapy. If you installed Scrapy with Python 2, the executable will use Python 2. Uninstall Scrapy and install it again, this time with Python 3, to get the executable to use Python 3.